# How to Convert String Response in telugu format in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

i got string response from server.Now i want to convert string response from english to telugu.how to convert this one.Please help me.This is my code.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

    if(connection==urlConnection)
    {

        NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"String Response is : %@",strResponse);

        NSRange r;        
        NSString * cleanString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:strResponse];

        while ((r = [cleanString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
            cleanString = [cleanString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@"\n"];

        [text1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Telugu Sangam MN Regular" size:30]];

        text1.text=cleanString;

    }
}
```

This is my string Response :

```
String Response is : &#3125;&#3135;&#3110;&#3135;&#3119;  &#3120;&#3134;  8. 31 &#3125;<br>&#3100;&#3149;&#3119;&#3143;&#3127;&#3149;&#3103; &#3120;&#3134;.3. 50 &#3125;<br>&#3125;.&#3081; 10.41 -12 .10 &#3125;<br>&#3110;&#3137;.&#3081;8.13 – 9 .04  &#3125;<br>(2) &#3118;.12.30 – 1.21
```

I want to convert like this:

```
శు. విదియ రా . 9 .11 వ

అశ్విని రా 11.56 వ

వ.రా 8.00-9.32 వ

. ఉ8.30 â€“ 9.20 వ

(2) రా. 11. 15- 12. 04 వ
```

Comment: But the response is in which format whether it is encrypted?

Comment: @iMobile yes bro.but i have no idea how to convertion this

Answer (score 0):

There is some quick solution may your problem solve for that follow steps

1. Add .TTF font in your application
2. Add the application-info.plist file
3. Add the key "Fonts provided by application" to a new row

Then after use following code for find your font name select your font name then place where you use those font

```
   NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
    NSArray *fontNames;
    NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
    for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
    {
        NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
        fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                     [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                      [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
        for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
        {
            NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
        }

    }
```

For more step by step instruction about custom font use [refer here](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/25/load-and-access-custom-fonts/)

******EDITED*******

Following code for implemented by myself and work good

```
[self.lblDtl setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"TeluguSangamMN" size:24]];
NSString *simpleText = @" &#3120;&#3134;  8. 31 &#3125;<br>&#3100;&#3149;&#3119;&#3143;&#3127;&#3149;&#3103; &#3120;&#3134;.3. 50 &#3125;<br>&#3125;.&#3081; 10.41 -12 .10 &#3125;<br>&#3110;&#3137;.&#3081;8.13 – 9 .04  &#3125;<br>(2) &#3118;.12.30 – 1.21";
simpleText = [simpleText stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];

[self.lblDtl setText:simpleText];
```

Comment: Bro could you add font in your project?

Comment: yes bro...I am adding Telugu Sangam MN.TTF added in plist bro

Comment: wait i will give you link and download there project i did it

Comment: Download Project from this URL http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/Font%20Demo/FontDemo.zip/download

Comment: if you satisfy with my answer please upvote my answer.

Comment: bro plz come to stack over flow chat and come to Talk-4-ios

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54493/discussion-between-nimit-parekh-and-user3222991).

Comment: i have some doubts. thats why plz come to Stack over flow chat and come to Talk4-ios